# How to convert gender in dataframes from integer to character using R

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataframe where gender is coded 1 and 0 for male and female respectively. It's not a replica, but looks something like this:

```
df <- read.csv("df.csv")

      "  Gender   Age    Width
1          0      35      1.4   
2          0      30      1.4  
3          1      32      1.3   
4          1      31      1.5    
5          0      36      1.4  
6          1      39      1.7  "
```

I've managed to change the class type of it to factor and gave it labels:

```
df$Gender <- as.factor(df$Gender)
class(df$Gender)

df$Gender <- factor(df$Gender,
levels = c("1","0"),
labels = c("male", "female"))
```

However, when I try to print df$Gender, I get all "NA" as my output

UPDATE:
Thank you all for your help!
I realised that my code works when I run it the first time. It only becomes "NA" when I rerun the second chunk. Will this be a problem or can I just ignore it?

Comment: Use `ifelse(df$Gender == 1,"male","female")`

Comment: @BappaDas I still get the same output

Comment: what is the output od `levels(df$Gender )`

Comment: @Roman [1] "male"   "female"

Comment: Please provide your data in `dput(df)` format. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Or use `factor(df1$Gender, labels = c("male", "female"))`.

Comment: @BappaDas Gender = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, .Label = c("male", "female"), class = "factor")

Comment: @BappaDas I got an error: "Error in factor(df$Gender, labels = c("male", "female")) : invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 0"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your input data. As per the description your code works fine on my computer, example input `df <- data.frame(gender = c(1L, 0L, 1L), x = 11:13)`.

Comment: What is the output of `read.csv("df.csv")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(gender = factor(Gender, labels = c("male", "female")))
```

or simply

```
df$gender <- ifelse(df$Gender == 1,"male","female")
```

or

```
df %>% 
  mutate(gender = if_else(Gender == 1,"male","female"))
```

or

```
df %>% 
  mutate(gender = case_when(Gender == 1 ~ "male",
                            Gender == 0 ~ "female"))
```

Data

```
df = structure(list(Sn = 1:6, Gender = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
    Age = c(35L, 30L, 32L, 31L, 36L, 39L), Width = c(1.4, 1.4, 
    1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), gender = c("female", "female", "male", 
    "male", "female", "male")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score -2):

Everything what you have done seems correct, when I reconstruct your input

```
Gender <- c(1,0,1,0)
Age <- c(50,30,40,30)

df <- data.frame(Gender,Age)
df$Gender <- factor(df$Gender,
                levels = c("1","0"),
                labels = c("male", "female"))
print(df$Gender)
```

if you really want is as character you can then add:

```
df$Gender <- as.character(df$Gender)
```

But I think (as others already mentioned) its because of your input data, therefore try to add stringasfactors to your import command:

```
df <- read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```